# DRF:Apply order by in nested Searilizer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Nested Representation:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'phone': 1023456789
        'stats': {
            'created': 1-09-2016,
            'result': 'fail',
            ...
        },
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'phone': 1023456789
        'stats': {
            'created': 13-09-2016,
            'result': 'pass',
        },
    },
]
```

I have 3 serializers:

```
class abcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created=Field(source='created')
    result = Field(source='result')

    class Meta:
        model = abc
        fields = ('created','result')
        order_by = ['-created']

class defSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created=Field(source='created')
    result = Field(source='result')
    class Meta:
        model = def
        fields =('created','result')
        order_by = ['-created']



class mainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    obj1 = abcSerializer()
    obj2 = defSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = main 
        '''
        main is model class.Contains fields as id,phone,stat
        '''
        fields = ('obj1','obj2')
```

In views.py

Accessing those serialized data:

```
data =  main.objects.filter(id=111)
serializer = mainSerializer(data)
return Response(record)
```

I want sort the searilized data on basis of field 'created' on descending order.

tried some SO link & then github link as [link](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1005) with no success.
github link is similar to my problem but it didn't address my solution.

Can some one point some solution to my problem!!

Comment: The meta attribute should be `ordering = ` and not `order_by`

Comment: Ordering = doesn't address my solution

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247490/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-order/48249910