# Django Rest-Framework nested serializer order

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to order a nested serializer `_set`, for example order by `pk` or `time-stamp`.

So basically order `song_set` shown in the json data below from the most recent to the latest object created, in this case by `order_by('-timestamp')` or `order_by('-pk')`.

**Json data**

```
{
    "pk": 151,
    "album_name": "Name",
    "song_set": [
         {
           pk: 3,
           timestamp: '5 seconds'
         },
         {
           pk: 2,
           timestamp: '10 seconds'
         },
         {
           pk: 1,
           timestamp: '15 seconds'
         }
    ]
}
```

**Model**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name     = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class Song(models.Model):
    album          = models.ForeignKey('album.Album', default=1)
    timestamp      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

**Serializer**

```
class SongListSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp'
        ]

class AlbumSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    song_set = SongListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp',
            'song_set'
        ]
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44418189

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` and write custom method for this.

```
class AlbumSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    song_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp',
            'song_set'
        ]

    def get_song_set(self, instance):
        songs = instance.song_set.all().order_by('-timestamp')
        return SongListSerializer(songs, many=True).data
```

Comment: How can I pass a variable to filter the values with a field?

Comment: You can pass data in serializer context.

Comment: I did that way, but was thinking like If I can pass the set of filtered instances along with the data like "AlbumSerializer(data,song_instances)" this is wrong but is ther ea similar way to directly pass instances to nested list serializer without using serializermethod()?

Comment: If you do not want to filter your data on the basis of your instance, than you can pass filtered instances to you serializer. If tou want to pass data directly to your nested serialized, than that data must be part of your queryset.

Comment: This will cause your schema generator to be unable to determine the type of `song_set` field. If using libraries like `drf_spectacular` you will need to `extend_schema_field` or at least provide a type hinting for the `get_song_set` property.

Answer (score 64):

Add **ordering** meta parameter to your Song model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('album.Album', default=1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp', 'pk']
```

Comment: This solved my issue when i didn't want to adopt the SerializerMethodField solution

Comment: Beware this will affect every use of the `Song` model. It's not limited to the serializer.

Comment: per what @djvg said, this is a bad idea performance wise

Answer (score 33):

In your `ViewSet`, you can specify a queryset with a custom `Prefetch` object that you can filter and order as you like. Prefetching causes just one additional database query (instead of one per parent object when using `SerializerMethodField`), giving vastly improved performance.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('song_set',
        queryset=Song.objects.order_by('-timestamp')))
```

Answer (score 8):

Old thread, but because it's still popping up on Google I want to share my answer as well. Try overwriting the `Serializer.to_representation` method. Now you can basically do whatever you want, including customising the sorting of your response. In your case:

```
class AlbumSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    song_set = SongListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp',
            'song_set'
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response["song_set"] = sorted(response["song_set"], key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])
        return response
```

Comment: I'm sure there could be a better way to do this. I think changing the order through the ModelManager could be a better approach. Not sure about it, though.

Comment: This looks like it could have run time performance impacts since sorting seems to be left to the server and the not the database.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to modify the `to_representation` method on the `ListSerializer` to change the ordering when the relationship is queried via the ORM.

This `to_representation` is similar to how it works for the base [`ListSerializer` in DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2510456817d9d2840a4080e69a0efb8a4da423ac/rest_framework/serializers.py#L680).

```py
class SongListSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp'
        ]

    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all().order_by('-timestamp', '-id') \
            if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        return [self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable]



class AlbumSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    song_set = SongListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'timestamp',
            'song_set'
        ]
```