# How to sort data from django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my code:

```py
class PackageMetaSerializer(ParameterBaseSerializer):
    expired_delta = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='calculate_delta', read_only=True)
    package = platforms_serializers.PackageSerializer(
        parameters=("uuid", "id", "name", "platform", "type", "period")
    )
    expire_date_datetime = serializers.DateField("%Y/%m/%d")

    class Meta:
        model = account_models.UserToPackageMeta
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 4

    def calculate_delta(self, instance):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        last_package = instance.expire_date_datetime
        return (last_package - today).days


class UserSerializer(ParameterBaseSerializer):
    packages = PackageMetaSerializer(
        read_only=True,
        many=True,
        source="package_metas",
        parameters=("id", "token", "created_date", "package", 'expired_delta'),
    )
    last_package = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name="get_last_package", read_only=True
    )
    has_active_package = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        "check_user_activity", read_only=True
    )
    is_profile_completed = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        "check_profile_completed")
    has_unread_notification = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    birth_date = PersianDateField(format="%Y/%m/%d", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = account_models.User
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
        depth = 4
```

Whenever I use the UserSerializer, I want the data to be sorted by the `expired_delta` I got from the other serializer.
How can I do that from the serializer side?

Sort data by expried date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247490/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-order
i think this is related to your question